# I am trying to solve a 6x6 sudoku in Python

Tags: python, sudoku, solution

I just don't get why i dont get a solution to this? 
Can someome point me in the right direction on how to find the solutoion to this?

When i try to input the number 1 - 6 it doesn't work. Just get the print "No Solution", so it skips the solution part of the code.

Thank you so much.

```
    SIZE = 6
# sudoku problem
# 0 is unknown cells
board = [
    [0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 6, 2, 4],
    [3, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2]]


# function to print sudoku
def print_sudoku():
    for i in board:
        print(i)


# Function to check if cells are unassigned and to add value to unassigned cells.
def unassigned_numbers(row, col):
    unassigned_num: int = 0
    for i in range(0, SIZE):
        for j in range(0, SIZE):
            # cell is unassigned
            if board[i][j] == 0:
                row = i
                col = j
                num_unassign = 1
                a = [row, col, num_unassign]
                return a
    a = [-1, -1, unassigned_num]
    return a


# function to check if a number can be assign a specific cell
def is_safe(n, r, c):
    # checking row
    for i in range(0, SIZE):
        # Cell has the same value
        if board[r][i] == n:
            return False
    # checking column
    for i in range(0, SIZE):
        # Cell has the same value
        if board[i][c] == n:
            return False
    row_start = (r // 2) * 3;
    col_start = (c // 3) * 2;
    # checking box
    for i in range(row_start, row_start + 3):
        for j in range(col_start, col_start + 2):
            if board[i][j] == n:
                return False
    return True


# Function to  check if we can put a value to a given cell
def solve_sudoku():
    row = 0
    col = 0
    # if all cells are assigned then the sudoku is already solved
    # pass by reference because number_unassigned will change the values of row and col
    a = unassigned_numbers(row, col)
    if a[2] == 0:
        return True
    row = a[0]
    col = a[1]
    # number between 1 to 6
    for i in range(1, 7):
        if is_safe(i, row, col):
            board[row][col] = i
            # backtracking
            if solve_sudoku():
                return True
            # if the solution don't work reassign the cell
            board[row][col] = 0
    return False


if solve_sudoku():
    print_sudoku()
else:
    print("No solution")
```

What can be the issue here? 
I am guessing it might be in this part:

## checking column

```
    for i in range(0, SIZE):
        # Cell has the same value
        if board[i][c] == n:
            return False
    row_start = (r // 2) * 3;
    col_start = (c // 3) * 2;
    # checking box
    for i in range(row_start, row_start + 3):
        for j in range(col_start, col_start + 2):
            if board[i][j] == n:
                return False
    return True
```

Hope someone can help me out :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure these calculations are right? Take `r=6` for example, this returns a `row_start` of `6`, adding `3` to this index will be out of bounds. Remember you want to check all the numbers in the given box.

```
(r // 2) * 2
r -> row_start
1 -> 0 
2 -> 2 
3 -> 2
4 -> 4
5 -> 4
6 -> 6

(c // 3) * 2
c -> col_start
1 -> 0
2 -> 0
3 -> 2
4 -> 2
5 -> 2
6 -> 4
```

Comment: I got the code to run, but the output was not as expected. It seems like there might be missing the boxes on the sudoku, since it only think about rows and columns. 
Can anyone point me in the right directions to this? 
How can i implement this in my code? tried so many things but im stuck!